# Do you have to capitalize a question that is after a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, capitalization

Do you have to capitalize a question that is after a comma?
Example:

> I'm not hungry, why do I have to eat?

EDIT

The sentence are formed by dependent clauses with the next structure:

Situation, question about the situation.

More examples:

> They have a luxury car, are they rich?
>
> If I don't study, will I pass the exam?
>
> I'm sure you received my letter, why didn't you answer me?

My question is: the words "are", "will" and "why" have to be capitalized?

Comment: I know of no such rule in English.  Is this perhaps a rule in your own language?

Comment: Nope you don't have to. You might want to check these resources for further reading: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp  and http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/questiontext.htm

Comment: I am not aware of such a rule in *any* language, not just English. If you saw this somewhere, please specify where exactly and in which context. And if you never saw this anywhere, then you shouldn't be inventing it.

Comment: It is however important to separate independent clauses by something other than a comma. Here, a colon, a semi-colon, or a dash are fine - or two sentences.

Comment: Yeah, this just looks like a grammatical error to me - or at least, it's a suspect usage. These are separate clauses that could stand alone as separate sentences.

Comment: The sentence are formed by dependent clauses with the next structure:

Situation, question about the situation.

More examples:

They have a luxury car, are they rich?
If I don't study, will I pass the exam?
I'm sure you received my letter, why didn't you answer me?

My question is: the words "are", "will" and "why" have to be capitalized?

Comment: Only the second of your three further examples avoids a comma splice; according to Wikipedia, "Although acceptable in some languages and compulsory in others, comma splices are usually considered style errors in English." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice . You're asking for guidance about rules. It's being offered. Your second (further) example is quite acceptable: _If I don't study, will I pass the exam?_ This is because one of the clauses is dependent. A capital should not be used for _will_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In American English, you may capitalize a question (or any [independent clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29#Use_of_capitals)) after a *colon* but not a comma:

> They have a luxury car: Are they rich?
>
> I'm sure you received my letter: Why didn't you answer me?

Also, the [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) is a style error in English: Prefer semicolons, colons, or periods for joining independent clauses.

Comment: What you've written isn't wrong, but there is some room for interpretation on the _to capitalize, or not to capitalize_ question (when following a colon, that is). More about that [here](http://www.apvschicago.com/2011/04/capitalization-after-colons.html), [here](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/), and [here](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/colon-grammar.aspx).

Comment: How about the following sentence?

**The perennial question has been, What is "hip?"**

The "W" should not be capitalized? I think a lowercase "w" would make the sentence less readable.  A colon instead of a comma would work. But again, I think it would be awkward.